# Amplifier input impedance matching to source (low frequencies)

Tags: amplifier, impedance

I'm curious as to what the benefits are of having an amplifier's input impedance exactly matched to that of the source?

For example, when measuring voltages, if the source impedance is between 500 Ohms and 10 kOhms (and varies over time) for a signal bandwidth of 100Hz-10kHz, is there any benefit to having the amplifier's input impedance matched exactly (or very close) to that of the source?

From my understanding, matching impedance exactly is only beneficial when working in the RF range (I may be wrong).

Comment: Probably not. Most likely the best thing will be to aim for an amplifier input impedance much higher than 10 kOhms to avoid signal attenuation when source impedance is 10 kOhms.

Answer (score 1):

Impedance matching is particularly important if you need [maximum power transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem), and the applications for this are many, ranging from audio outputs to antenna drive.

In a high speed and RF world, impedance matching is necessary to prevent 
[signal reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_reflection); this becomes an issue if the physical distance between a driver and receiver is greater than about 1/10 of a signal rise or fall time (rule of thumb: the [strict limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations) is far smaller). This is part of [transmission line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line) theory and application.

Another RF application is matching an antenna (which is normally in free space with an impedance of 377 ohms) to the internal transceiver circuitry (which is commonly at 50 or 75 ohms), as maximum power transfer is particularly important here, for both transmit and receive operation.

Providing none of these apply (such as a low frequency amplifier chain), then generally a receiver input impedance should be much larger than the source impedance - once more, a rule of thumb is a factor of 10.

The above assumes voltage amplifiers. Current amplifiers (a smaller but very important class of amplifiers) have low input impedance and high output impedance and are worthy of a discussion in their own right.

HTH